# Fourier Transform of rational function

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

So I have this function:

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{(1-it)^{n+1}}$$

And I have the Fourier Transform defined as

$$\hat{f}(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)e^{-\lambda.it}dt $$

Now my exercise is to prove that:

$\hat{f}=Ce^{-\lambda}*\lambda^n$ for $\lambda >0$ and $0$ otherwise for some constant $C$

I am having problems with the integration tried doing it by parts but i never get anything conclusive.

Comment: Put dollar-signs $ around your latex to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, so what we need to show is that $$
  C\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n e^{i\lambda t} \,d\lambda = \frac{1}{(1-it)^{n+1}} \text{.}
$$
We have $$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n e^{i\lambda t} \,d\lambda
  = \int_0^\infty \underbrace{\lambda^n}_{u} \underbrace{e^{it\lambda-\lambda}}_{v'} \,d\lambda
 &=& \underbrace{\lambda^n\frac{e^{it\lambda-\lambda}}{(it-1)}\Bigg|_0^\infty}_{=0} 
    -n\int_0^\infty \underbrace{\lambda^{n-1}}_{=u'}\underbrace{\frac{e^{it\lambda-\lambda}}{(it-1)}}_{=v} \,d\lambda \\
 &=& \frac{-n}{it - 1} \int_0^\infty \lambda^{n-1}e^{it\lambda-\lambda} \,d\lambda \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Doing this repeatedly shows that $$
  I_n = \frac{n}{1 - it} I_{n-1} \text{ where } I_n = \int_0^\infty \lambda^n e^{it\lambda - \lambda} \,d\lambda \text{.}
$$
Since $I_0 = \frac{e^{it\lambda - \lambda}}{it -1 }\bigg|_0^\infty = \frac{1}{it - 1}$, it follows that $$
  \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n e^{i\lambda t} \,d\lambda = I_n = \frac{n!}{(1 - it)^{n+1}} \text{,}
$$
and thus that $$
  \hat f(\lambda) = \underbrace{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{n!}\right)}_{=C}\,e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n
  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  f(t) = \frac{1}{(1 - it)^{n+1}} \text{.}
$$

---

You can also directly compute the forward transform $\hat f$ of your $f$, i.e. $$
  \hat f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(z) \,dz \text { where }
  h(z) = \frac{e^{-i\lambda z}}{(1 - iz)^{n+1}}
$$
by contour integration.

The integrand can be rewritten as $$
  h_\lambda(z) = i^{n+1}\frac{e^{-i\lambda z}}{(z + i)^{n+1}} \text{,}
$$
which has a single pole at $z=-i$. Let $\gamma_N^\lambda$ be the closed path that goes from $-N$ to $N$ along the real axis and then back to $-N$ along a half-circle $C^\lambda_N$ in the upper half plane if $\lambda \leq 0$, and the same path except the half-circle $C^\lambda_N$ lies in the lower half plane if $\lambda > 0$ instead. Note that $z=-i$ only lies within $\gamma_N^\lambda$ if $\lambda > 0$, i.e. the contour integral is zero otherwise. Also note that for $\lambda < 0$, the contour goes around $z=-i$ clock-wise. 
The inequalities $$\begin{eqnarray}
  |(z + i)^{n+1}| &=& |z + i|^{n+1} \geq (|z| - 1)^{n+1} \\
  |e^{-i\lambda z}| &=& e^{\lambda\textrm{Im}(z)} \leq \begin{cases}
    1 &\text{if $\lambda > 0$, $\textrm{Im}(z) < 0$} \\
    1 &\text{if $\lambda \leq 0$, $\textrm{Im}(z) > 0$} \\
  \end{cases} \\
  \int_{C^\lambda_N} h_\lambda(z) \,dz &\leq& \pi N \sup_{C^\lambda_N} h(z) \leq \pi \frac{N}{(N - 1)^{n+1}}
\end{eqnarray}$$
show that for $n > 0$, $\int_{C^\lambda_N} h(z) \,dz \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$, and it follows that $$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) \,dt = \oint_{\gamma^\lambda_N} h(z) \,dz
  = \begin{cases}
    -i2\pi\textrm{Res}(h,-i) &\text{if $\lambda > 0$} \\
    0 &\text{if $\lambda \leq 0$.}
  \end{cases}
$$

So all that remains to do is to compute the residue of $h$ at $z=-i$. Since $h(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ where $p(z)$ is holomoprhic at $z=-i$ and $q(z)$ has a zero of order $n+1$ at $z=-i$, we have  $$
  \textrm{Res}(h,-i)
  = \frac{1}{n!}\lim_{z\to -i} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} \left((z + i)^{n+1} h(z)\right)
  = \frac{1}{n!}p^{(n)}(-i)
  = \frac{i^{n+1}(-i\lambda)^n}{n!}e^{-i\lambda(-i)}
  = \frac{i}{n!}\lambda^ne^{-\lambda} \text{.}
$$

Therefore, for $n > 0$, $$\begin{eqnarray}
  \hat f(\lambda) &=& \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(i2\pi\right)\left(-\frac{i}{n!}\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}\right)
      &\text{if $\lambda > 0$} \\
    0 &\text{if $\lambda \leq 0$}
  \end{cases} \\
  &=& \begin{cases}
    \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{n!}\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}
      &\text{if $\lambda > 0$} \\
    0 &\text{if $\lambda \leq 0$.}
  \end{cases} \\\end{eqnarray}
$$
That case $n = 0$ needs to be handled separately.

Comment: thanks! it never occuried to me doing it using the inverse.

Comment: @jmatist You're welcome. I had the constant $C$ wrong - I had forgotten the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ in the inverse transform. Just for the fun of it I added a direct computation of the forward transform using contour integration. Looks more complicated than it is - all these inequalities are pretty obvious by just looking at the integrand.